# Positivity of dot product in complex vector space (Theorem $12.11$ in Tom Apostol's Calculus vol. 1)

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces

First, in exercise $9.6.7$, Tom Apostol asked us to prove that we cannot introduce ordering of complex numbers, such that all the 3 axioms are satisfied:

1. If $x, y \in C^+$, so are $x+y$ and $xy$.
2. For every real $x \ne 0$, either $x \in C^+$ or $-x \in C^+$, but not both.
3. $0 \notin C^+$

Now in section $12.16$, when motivating the definition of a dot product in complex vector space $V_n(C)$, he wrote that

> Since a sum of squares of complex numbers can be negative, we must modify the definition of $A \cdot B$ if we wish to retain the positive property.

And then he defines the dot product as $A \cdot B = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k \overline{b_k}$, so the positive property holds: $A \ne 0 \implies A \cdot A > 0$.

I understand that if $A = i$, the usual dot product would be negative, just because it happens to be a real scalar. However, I don't understand how can we assume in general that a complex number (which is the result of $A \cdot A$ even with the new definition) can be negative.

How should I understand that? Did he mean that it should at least not be negative when the dot product is a real scalar?

Comment: Why do you think he assumes the dot product could be "a negative complex numbers "(there is no such a thing, of curse)? It is only that if the dot product in unitary spaces isn't defined that way it can be that $\;A\cdot A=0\;$ without $\;A=0\;$  being true, and that cannot happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isnot being assumed a complex number is negative, as commented above. For example, in $\;\Bbb C^2\;$ we'd get, if we don't use the complex conjugate:

$$\binom 1i\cdot\binom 1i=1+i^2=1-1=0\,\;\;\text{but of course}\;\;\binom1i\neq\binom00 ...$$

Instead, he (and everybody else) defines

$$\binom 1i\cdot\binom 1i=1\cdot\overline 1+i\cdot\overline i=1+i\cdot(-1)=1+1=2>0 \;\;(\text{ in the reals)}$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you please then explain what *is* being assumed with "Since a sum of squares of complex numbers can be negative"?

Comment: @S11n That means what it says: the sum of squares in the complex realm can be a real negative number. For example $\;i^2+i^2=-2\;$ . The implicit assumption when we work with complex number is that if in some given moment we talk of apositive or negative number, it is because that number is a real number. There is no linear order as we have in the reals, and the reason is precisely what you ask: that there are sum of squares in that field that negative.

Comment: Thanks! So it is indeed my suspicion from the last question I indicated, that he meant only in case when the dot product is a real scalar.